# How to modify my Python code with win32com module to save Excel file without pressing 'Save' button after running VBA script?

Tags: python

I want to save a file, on top of my old file, after python running VBA script, but problem that I every time need press 'Save' to overwrite my old file, what I can do with this code, to make press Save automatic ?  When I write `workbook.Save()` before `excel.Quit()` its creating new excel file

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'.....output.xlsx')
vb_module = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)  # 1= vbext_ct_StdModule
macro_code = '''
Sub MoveAndSizePictures()
    Dim pic As Shape
    For Each pic In Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        If pic.Type = msoPicture Then
            pic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End If
    Next pic
End Sub
'''
vb_module.CodeModule.AddFromString(macro_code)
excel.Run('MoveAndSizePictures')
workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove(vb_module)
excel.Quit()
```